# Excel - How to lock cell without using macros if possible

Tags: excel

I have solution implemented using the macro but I want remove it if I can. So here the issue

I have drop-down implemented using validation rule on a cell. I want that cell to be readonly depending on the value in second cell on same sheet.

I tried locking the using another validation but it don't allow me.

Any Idea?

Comment: how have you tried to prevent user from entering value? It should work using a formula

Comment: more detail in this question would really help

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that the data validation is in cell `A2` and the value which you are checking is in Cell `A1`

When you change the value of cell `A1` to "Blah Blah" the code will run and then lock cell `A2`. Please take a moment to read through the comments in the code before you actually run it.

The code has to be pasted in the worksheet code area.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim mypassword As String, StringToCheck As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change the password here to protect/unprotect the sheet
    mypassword = "password"

    '~~> Change it to the relevant string with which you want to compare
    StringToCheck = "Blah Blah"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check for the cell value
        If Target.Value = StringToCheck Then
            '~~> Un-Protect the sheet
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect mypassword

            '~~> Lock the cell
            Range("A2").Locked = True

            '~~> Re-Protect the sheet
            ActiveSheet.Protect mypassword
        End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but I like I already solution using macro(vba) I want remove to make work with .xlsx and work on tablets

Comment: So you don't want a VBA solution. is that what you are saying?

Comment: Then why mention macros in your post title and in the tags :)

Comment: i have macro i want to remove it :)

Comment: Ok. I have amended your post title. :) But just to let you know, AFAIK, you cannot do it without macros.

Answer (score 6):

You can prevent a user entering new data using only `Data Validation`

**EDIT: use formula in list**

Thanks to [Head of Catering](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138938/head-of-catering)'s comment, it is worth remembering that you can use formulas with Data Validation / List.

See his answer to another thread to see this in action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902463/138938

**Original post**

Walkthrough for Excel 2007:

- Ribbon > Data > Data Validation
- Authorize : Personnalized (or similar, my Excel is not in English sorry)
- Enter this formula in the field:

  - `=IF(A1="",FALSE,TRUE)`

Thus, you cannot enter a value in the cell if A1 is still empty

Comment: I already validation rule to create drop-down on the cell. it doesn't allow me to add the second validation to same cell

Comment: @user1598124: Can you use and `OR` and `AND` statement in your validation rule formula to meet your 2 validation requirements?

Comment: @user1598124: I don't know any standard way to add a second validation and I didn't find any dropdown solution without Data Validation. At last, I can't see how we could solve your issue without VBA

Comment: @Scott Holtzman I don't see any option in validation for doing that

Comment: @user1598124, yes, I just tried to play with my idea, but it hasn't worked like I thought it might.

Comment: You can also select **list** in data validation and enter the if formula with lists as your arguments. @JMax, I modified your approach to answer a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902463/138938

Comment: @HeadofCatering: very good trick! IMO, this would even be **the** answer to the OP's issue (no VBA, protected cells and lists). I've edited my answer to highlight your solution and add a link to your  answer

Comment: Good team work, @JMax. Your answer was so close, I didn't want to post a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work, but you can only actually set the value when it works out to a dropdown

I used Name Manager to set the name `test` to the value `=IF(Sheet1!$A$1=1,"",Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5)`

this means that if `A1` is 1, I get nothing, and if `A1` is anything else I get E1:E5

Then I set the data validation to `List`, with source to `=test`
*you can only set the value when **test** returns a list*

When I do this, when A1 is 1, I get an empty list in my validation dropdown, and I can't change the value. If A1 is not 1, I get my list of E1:E5, and I can change the value

Comment: +1 Interesting approach, but I tested it and it certainly doesn't lock the cell: when A1 is 1, you don't get a dropdown, but you can actually type in any value at all and the validation won't complain.

Comment: This is similar to Head of Catering solution (see his comment to my answer) but his solution is more straightforward and might work. Nice suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I found a solution that will throw an error AND prevent peeps from entering whatever they want (using Excel 2010) without using VBA.

On the user interface (SHEET1), I have the following fields:

- Field 1 is a Yes/No Validation Dropdown list.
- Field 2 is a percent validation Dropdown list with values of 1% -
  100%.

**What I needed:**

- When "Yes" is selected, I can choose or type 1%-100% in field 2.  It is also "available".
- When "No" is selected, field 2 becomes "grayed out" and user can no longer enter some random value.

**How I did it:**

1. For field 2, I used a Conditional Formatting (formula of ='SHEET2'!$I$2="No") and set it to gray out the font and background.
2. In SHEET2, I set a field (column I) to equal field 1 from SHEET1, so it's either "Yes" or "No" depending on what's selected in field 1 from SHEET1.  I then simply added 99 other rows beneath it, setting them equal to the cell immediately above it.  So I have a 100 rows of "Yes" or "No".
3. In SHEET2, I have another column (R) with the first cell value of:  =IF(I2="Yes", 0.01, 1)
4. Immediately below it, I have:  =IF(I3="Yes", R2+0.01, 1)
5. I then prefill the values down the rows below it until I have 1% throuh 100% (when "Yes" is selected) and set the validation on SHEET1's field 2 to be based on these values.  This allows me to manually enter a % value, or select from the dropdown values 1% through 100%.

**Results:**

When I select "No", it grays out field 2, and leaves the % whatever it was before because it can't change the displayed value without VBA.  For example, it might still show 30%.  However, if the user sees it grayed out and attempts to type some value in it, like 31%, it'll throw an error since I set an ERROR on the "Error Alert" tab in Data Validation for this field.  If they choose the dropdown, they just see like 100 options of 100%.  This is the only downside, but I guess I could have just blanked out everything except 1 single field showing 100%.

When I choose "Yes", it ungrays field 2, and I am free to choose from the doprdown list values between 1-100 again.

**What I needed to do with the values:**

For whatever it is I need to accomplish, I set some formula I'm using based on 100% if "No" is selected and field 2's % if "Yes" is selected.