# Look up Column number in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the filter option to filter my range.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="yes"
```

Basically that will filter Column U for yes.
What I have is a dropdown list and I need it to find what field that entry is in for that range.  For example, Column U contains the name "John"

So if I select John from the drop down, it will need to look at the range, find the column John and then return what field it is (in this case its 11)

In column T is the name Ben.  If I select Ben from the drop down list then it will do the same filter but the field will be 10.

Is there anyway I can calculate the field number depending on what has been selected from the drop down?

```
    Sub Report()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim nice As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set oSht = Sheets("Overview")
    lastRow = oSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Dropdown").ControlFormat
    strSearch = .List(.Value)
End With
    MsgBox strSearch
    Set aCell = oSht.Range("K2:Z100").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
         nice = aCell.Column - 10
        ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=nice, Criteria1:="yes"

        End If
End Sub
```

So this is how I got it working.   Now I just need to know how to store the option from the dropdown as a variable and setup a macro to clear the filters and its a go!
PS - Couldn't get the last column finding bit to work as it kept saying "Object Required" so manually set it instead

Comment: Do a `.Find` and the use aCell.Column to get the column number of that column. Once you get that, simply subtract it from `10 (11-1)` where `11` is the column number of `K` in the spreadsheet. See this on how to do a `.Find` http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Give it a try and if you get stuck then show the code that you tried and we will take it from there :)

Comment: Thanks. How do I capture what option has been selected from the drop down list though?

Comment: Excellent!  Done it.  Just need to capture the input from the dropdown and its complete.  Updated question with ansqwer

Comment: Kool ;) You can trap the value from the Dropdown using `Worksheet_Change` event. If you search SO, I have answered similar question where you need to trap the value from the drop down.

Comment: BTW + 1 For showing Efforts ;) I could have given you the code directly but then I am sure you wouldn't have the same fun as you are having now in solving the problem. ;) Correct?

Comment: Does that not just run the VBA when the spread sheet changes and I need to trap the value from the drop down?

Comment: Yes that will run anytime there is a chnage in the spreadsheet and hence you will have to trap the changes to a particular cell using `Intersect` method.

Comment: I've used With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Dropdown").ControlFormat and then .List(.Value) however I get a runtime error 5 message now

Comment: Code updated to show progression

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953214/excel-how-to-lock-cell-without-using-macros-if-possible

Comment: Interesting discussion, but I'm wondering if you could put the answer in the answer box, so it looks like this question has been taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

You can use acell's current region property to get the column number within the region,see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018809/macro-explanation/24019440#24019440)

```
Sub Report()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim nice As Long
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set oSht = Sheets("Overview")
    lastRow = oSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Dropdown").ControlFormat
        strSearch = .List(.Value)
    End With

    MsgBox strSearch

    Set aCell = oSht.Range("K2:Z100").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        'nice = aCell.Column - 10
        'ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=nice, Criteria1:="yes"
        ''''''
         With aCell
           nice = aCell.Column - .CurrentRegion.Cells(1).Column + 1
           ActiveSheet.Range("$K$2:$ZZ$200").AutoFilter Field:=nice,Criteria1:="yes" 'Criteria1:=aCell
         End With
    End If
End Sub
```

and then use combination of

```
Sub ClearCombo()
With Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
    .Clear
End

Sub showAllData()
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

as needed to clear the combo box selection and show all data