# Trigger an event in Excel VBA from a data validation drop down

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have a sheet where I want to give the user a choice of calculation types.  The calculation types are done via a list selection in Data validation.  Once selected, I want it to trigger an event which will then load the correct cells for that type of selection.  How do I detect a data change event on the Data validation drop down or do I need to use the active x control for this?

Code for the worksheet change event not activating:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo Errortrap


'~~> Change it to the relevant string with which you want to compare
StringToCheck = "+"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D47")) Is Nothing Then
    '~~> Check for the cell value
    If Target.Value = StringToCheck Then
      'setup row to capture addition fields
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Input File 1"
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Worksheet 1"
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Cell 1"
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Input File 2"
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Worksheet 2"
       Cells(33, 4).Value = "Cell 2"
    End If
End If

LetsContinue:
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Exit Sub
Errortrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been covered many times in the past. Do a search in SO. See this code sample that I posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953214/excel-how-to-lock-cell-without-using-macros-if-possible

Comment: I did a search, and didn't find anything- must have used the wrong search terms

Comment: Have updated the comment above with a link. You have to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to trap the changes to the cell which has a DV.

Comment: Hmm,  now the question is why aren't change events being detected in my workbook?  Calculation is set to automatic and I have even added even added "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic" to the worksheet.activate event

Comment: Maybe because the `EnableEvents` are switched off? See this link. See point 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640 Do this. Press CTL G to popup the Immediate Window and then type this in the immediate window `?application.EnableEvents = True` and then try again. Also it would help if you update your question with the code that you are trying...

Comment: @ siddharth Rot Thanks, I tried to enable the events, still no luck- no response to a change in the worksheet.  I added the code I am using in the worksheet change event above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23694/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-marc-l)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. 
I tried it in a new workbook and it does just what it supposed to do.
When you change the value in **D47** to "+" (whether by dropdown or manually) it writes six values one after another in a cell **D33**.

Maybe you meant to write

```
        Cells(33, 4).Value = "Input File 1"
        Cells(33, 5).Value = "Worksheet 1"
        Cells(33, 6).Value = "Cell 1"
        Cells(33, 7).Value = "Input File 2"
        Cells(33, 8).Value = "Worksheet 2"
        Cells(33, 9).Value = "Cell 2"
```

so the code will fill range **D33:I33** rather than writing everything into **D33**.